# Gatling Proxy configuration fails

Tags: scala, gatling

When doing this

```
val HTTP_PROTOCOL = http
    .proxy(Proxy("proxy", 8080))
```

I have this when launching my tests

```
too many arguments (2) for method apply:(v1:io.gatling.core.session.Session)io.gatling.commons.validation.Validation[Proxy.type] in trait Function1
    .proxy(Proxy("proxy", 8080))
```

The doc doesn't mention anything about anything else

https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol#response-handling-parameters

I'm using the latest versions available

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <gatling.version>3.3.1</gatling.version>
    <gatling-maven-plugin.version>3.0.5</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>
```

Any idea as it may be some Scala issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proxy` can be invoked:

- either on an HttpProtocol like in [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/3.3/gatling-http/src/test/scala/io/gatling/http/compile/HttpCompileTest.scala#L36)
- or on an HttpRequestBuilder like in [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/3.3/gatling-http/src/test/scala/io/gatling/http/compile/HttpCompileTest.scala#L274)

So either you're not calling it at the right place, or you've messed up with the Gatling imports, which should strictly be like in [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/3.3/gatling-http/src/test/scala/io/gatling/http/compile/HttpCompileTest.scala#L21-L22).

> The doc doesn't mention anything about anything else

The correct links to the doc about `proxy` are:

- https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol#proxy-parameters
- https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request#outgoing-proxy

Comment: Thanks !

It was due to messed up imports.